# Flurry:Ad server responded but sent no ad units

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I am Using Flurry ads in my android  Application.
I have created one AdSpace on flurry server and accessing it in my application.
And I don’t have any Campaign as I want ads only from AppCircle. However, I am able to get test ads, But when I trying to get actual ads using flurry AppCircle(by setting `enableTeastAds(false)`) it shows following error,

```
Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
```

How can i solve it? do i need to configure Campaign to receive ads from flurry Appcircle?

this is my logcat output.

```
    06-05 15:55:26.984: D/FlurryAgent(575): Loading API key: ****************WFGX
06-05 15:55:26.984: D/FlurryAgent(575): Loading phoneId: ID3fcb04870193dd4c
06-05 15:55:26.984: D/FlurryAgent(575): Loading session reports
06-05 15:55:26.984: D/FlurryAgent(575): Persistent file loaded
06-05 15:55:27.054: D/FlurryAgent(575): generating report
06-05 15:55:27.054: D/FlurryAgent(575): Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
06-05 15:55:27.585: D/dalvikvm(575): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4475 objects / 293168 bytes in 61ms
06-05 15:55:28.005: D/dalvikvm(575): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4063 objects / 282008 bytes in 49ms
06-05 15:55:28.114: D/dalvikvm(575): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 198 objects / 8744 bytes in 34ms
06-05 15:55:28.326: D/FlurryAgent(575): Report successful
06-05 15:55:28.326: D/FlurryAgent(575): Done sending initial agent report
06-05 15:55:28.485: I/FlurryAgent(575): Request successful
06-05 15:55:28.485: I/FlurryAgent(575): Request successful
06-05 15:55:28.524: E/FlurryAgent(575): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
06-05 15:55:28.524: I/AdListener(575): space Did Fail To Receive Ad:AppCircle_Ads
```

**Note**:I am testing it on emulator.
         when tried to run on actual device, it didn't show test ads(nothing worked on actual device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try removing the call to FlurryAgent.initializeAds? 
This call should only be necessary if Ad Pre-caching is enabled in the ad space settings. Removing this line should prevent the error ""Ad server responded but send no Ad units" from being encountered.

Also, since your ads are getting displayed in the test mode, it appears to be an issue of availability of ads in the location of your testing.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)